# Use of \scshape or \textsc in beamer \institute

Tags: fonts, beamer, small-caps

I need to set a piece of my `\institute` name in small caps in my beamer presentation.

Now I set:

```
\institute{Dipartimento di Tecnologie dell'Infomazione \\ Corso di Laurea 
  in: {\scshape Sicurezza dei Sistemi e delle Reti Informatiche}}
```

but the small caps setting is completely ignored. Same for `\textsc{}`

Any clue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces or enclose words in backticks `\``, they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The small caps command has not the desired effect if your font doesn't provide a small caps shape. If necessary, switch to a font family which supports it. Here's an example showing that it works with `\rmfamily`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{A sample document}
\subtitle{for demonstrating small caps in an institute name}
\author{Author}
\institute{Dipartimento di Tecnologie dell'Infomazione \\
  Corso di Laurea  in: {\rmfamily\scshape Sicurezza dei Sistemi e delle
  Reti Informatiche}}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: institute on title page with small caps]

So the solution is, choose another font or at least another font weight, family or shape of which there's a small caps variant.

Comment: Aren't you missing something before `\scshape`?

Comment: @egreg That line is a copy of the code in the OP's question. We could insert `\rmfamily` before `\scshape`, as there's no sans serif small caps shape here. Though LaTeX switches for us, I added `\rmfamily` to be on the safe side.

Comment: i am using this theme http://blog.barisione.org/2007-09/torino-a-pretty-theme-for-latex-beamer/ setting `\institute{Dipartimento di Tecnologie dell'Infomazione \\ Corso di Laurea in: \\{\rmfamily \scshape Sicurezza dei Sistemi e delle Reti Informatiche}}` the small caps works

Comment: This does not work for me, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

add \usepackage{lmodern} in the preambula. 
This is about latinmodernroman:
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/latinmodernroman/

Answer (score 1):

I just came to this question and answer and think that the following link to the `LaTeX Font Catalogue` could be a good source for looking at fonts with small caps (or other demands): See therefore: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ for browsing and searching in it.