# Avoiding increase of number of fonts (families) with fontspec/xelatex?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

(*I actually came to a solution with this, which I've [posted separately](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56192/2595), but I thought it'd be good to document anyways - and of course, any comments to this are welcome*)

This is the problem - I need to "style fonts" in a document, which I compile using `xelatex` and `fontspec`. And it seems each time I call `\setmainfont` or `\fontspec` or `\addfontfeature` (which I thought are for "styling"), a new "font family" gets created.

Below is an MWE, that generates the following output (compiled with `xelatex test.tex`):

[image: test.png]

Note that each call to abovementioned functions causes 'Junicode(X+1)' to be instantiated; thankfully, `\fontsize{size}{skip}` doesn't seem to increase the number of fonts.

Here is the code (inline links: [1](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node36.html),
[2](http://www.forkosh.com/pstex/latexcommands.htm),
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56097/2595),
[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/2595),
[5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/2595)
):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

% http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node36.html
% dumps to log
% \usepackage{tracefnt}

% \typeout{ == \the\paperwidth / \the\paperheight ==}
% \typeout{ == \the\pdfpagewidth / \the\pdfpageheight ==}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth \pdfpageheight=\paperheight

% default font change:
% http://www.forkosh.com/pstex/latexcommands.htm
%   \fontencoding{T1}
%   \fontfamily{garamond}
%   \fontseries{m}
%   \fontshape{it}
%   \fontsize{12}{15}
%   \selectfont


\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}


% trick for fake smallcaps, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56097/2595
% each \setmainfont / \fontspec / \addfontfeature command creates a new Junicode(X) font
% here we are at Junicode(0)
% create Junicode(1) with fake bold
\fontspec[FakeBold=2.5]{Junicode}

% map Junicode(0)/bx/sc (bold smallcaps) to Junicode(1)/m/sc (normal smallcaps of fake bold)
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{Junicode(0)}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * Junicode(1)/m/sc}{}

% for debugging fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/2595
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{Encoding: \f@encoding{},
  Family: \f@family{},
  Series: \f@series{},
  Shape: \f@shape{},
  Size: \f@size{}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}


% from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/2595
% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}

\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
   \par%
%    \reversemarginpar%
%    \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill\parnum]{\parnum}}%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\reversemarginpar{\makebox[20pt][r]{\hfill\parnum.\space}}}%
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{parnumbers}

  {\scshape \showfont Aa}

  {\fontspec[Letters=SmallCaps]{Junicode} \showfont Aa}

  {\bfseries\scshape \showfont Aa}

  \showfont Aa

  \normalsize \showfont Aa

  \fontspec[Scale=1.0] {Junicode} \showfont Aa

  \addfontfeature{Scale=1.0} \showfont Aa

  \fontsize{9}{10} \showfont Aa

  \fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont \showfont Aa

  \addfontfeature{Scale=0.9} \showfont Aa

  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \showfont Aa

  \normalsize \showfont Aa

  \begin{tikzpicture} \node { \normalsize \showfont Aa }; \end{tikzpicture}

  \showfont Aa

\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes, new font families are created. But why does it worry you? A font family is simply a label. fontspec has to sort all your font definitions in the existing nfss-system. Which axis of the nfss system (encoding, family, shape, series, sizes) should a change like `Letters=SmallCaps` or `Ligatures=TeX` use instead? If you would use the shape or series axis you would not be able to combine your font with commands like `\bfseries` or `\itshape`.

In an extended nfss-system with more axis fontspec could use one of them. But in this case you would get new values in this axis. It would be a bit more cleaner and logical, but not more.

Comment: Thanks for that @UlrikeFischer - that clarifies things up.. I was worried, because I didn't think of a "font family" as a label - but as something big instantiated in memory; and secondly, I was worried that when I used commands that I thought restore a previous font, instead "instantiated" a new one. I was clearly not thinking in terms of NFSS-axis (more like OOP mixed with CSS instead `:)`) So I'll accept this answer; otherwise code that clarifies that for me is in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56215/2595). Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I'll post this here, as I thought it is related, and somewhat unobvious - and the question being: how do you refer to a font set by `setmainfont` in the preamble ?!

The trick is basically, to use `\newfontfamily` right after - and with  *exactly the same parameters* as - a call to `\setmainfont` in the preamble.

For example, this is a "proper" MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth \pdfpageheight=\paperheight


\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}


\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}                   % Junicode(0)
\newfontfamily\mfontfam[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}        % Junicode(0) !!

\newfontfamily\mfontFamFkBd[FakeBold=2.5]{Junicode} % Junicode(1)

% map Junicode(0)/bx/sc (bold smallcaps) to Junicode(1)/m/sc (normal smallcaps of fake bold)
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{Junicode(0)}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * Junicode(1)/m/sc}{}

\newfontfamily\mfontFamA[Scale=0.8]{Junicode}       % Junicode(2)
\newfontfamily\mfontFamB[Scale=1.5]{Junicode}       % Junicode(3)



% for debugging fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/2595
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{Encoding: \f@encoding{},
  Family: \f@family{},
  Series: \f@series{},
  Shape: \f@shape{},
  Size: \f@size{}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}


% from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/2595
% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}

\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
   \par%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\reversemarginpar{\makebox[20pt][r]{\hfill\parnum.\space}}}%
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{parnumbers}

  \mfontfam \showfont
  \typeout{ == \showfont}

  \mfontFamFkBd \showfont
  \typeout{ == \showfont}

  \mfontFamA \showfont
  \typeout{ == \showfont}

  \mfontFamB \showfont
  \typeout{ == \showfont}

\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

If you compile this with `xelatex test.tex`, you will get to stdout:

```
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(0){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(1){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(2){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{} 
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(3){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
```

and in the log file:

```
$ grep created test.log 
. Font family 'Junicode(0)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(0)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(1)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(2)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(3)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
```

... and it can be easily checked that `\mfontfam` refers to "Junicode(0)".

However, note that if, say, the "Scale" parameter is different - even if the font stays the same - as in:

```
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Junicode}                   % Junicode(0)
\newfontfamily\mfontfam[Scale=1.5]{Junicode}        % Junicode(?) !!
```

... then there will be problems: stdout will note:

```
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(1){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(2){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(3){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
 == Encoding: EU1{}, Family: Junicode(1){}, Series: m{}, Shape: n{}, Size: 12{}
```

... - a completely wrong order of fonts; and so will the log file inform us that about something similar:

```
$ grep created test.log 
. Font family 'Junicode(0)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(1)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(2)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(3)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. Font family 'Junicode(1)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
```

... ( and obviously, in this case the font mapping trick (*as in `\mfontfam \bfseries\scshape \showfont...`*) for small caps doesn't work anymore, as the mapping references are now inaccurate ). And notably, now `\mfontfam` will restore "Junicode(1)" (instead of "Junicode(0)", as it did in the example initially).

Well, just thought I'd jot this down - hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

---

EDIT: And one more thing; note that if, instead of the abovenoted `\newfontfamily`:

```
\newfontfamily\mfontFamB[Scale=1.5]{Junicode}
...
  \mfontFamB \showfont
```

(... which generates the following in the log:

```
$ grep -A 1 created test.log
...
--
. Font family 'Junicode(3)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.5].
```

)
... you use `\newfontface`, as in:

```
\newfontface\mfontFacB[Scale=1.5]{Junicode}
...
  \mfontFacB \showfont
```

... then you will get warnings like:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Junicode(3)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/Junicode(3)/m/n' instead on input line 60.
```

... which are explained by the `fontspec` entry in the log:

```
$ grep -A 1 created test.log
...
--
. Font family 'Junicode(3)' created for font 'Junicode' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Scale=1.5].
```

That is:

- `newfontface` causes: `[Ligatures=TeX,BoldFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Scale=1.5]`
- `\newfontfamily` causes: `[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1.5]`

... or, `newfontface` explicitly sets bold/italic/smallcaps options of fonts to null; while `newfontfamily` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are commands `\newfontface` and `\newfontfamily` in `fontspec`. What confused we is that when I see something with "new", I think of instantiating objects (+ more memory) - when I see something with "set" or "add", I think of changing properties; here it works somewhat the opposite `:)`

In the following example, note that `\newfontface` does create a new font family, but it also provides a command which allows one to switch back to that same font; but notably, it doesn't in itself switch the font formatting. On the other hand, `\newfontfamily` will not do any changes in formatting - and will seemingly refer to the earliest instance of a font (here "Junicode(0)") - and the command which gets defined by using it will also allow a reset back to this instance.

Here is the output of the MWE:

[image: test.png]

... and here is the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth \pdfpageheight=\paperheight


\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Junicode}


% each \setmainfont / \fontspec / \addfontfeature command creates a new Junicode(X) font
% here we are at Junicode(0)
% create Junicode(1) with fake bold
\fontspec[FakeBold=2.5]{Junicode}
% also possible with \newfontface (so we can reference it if we need to)?
% \newfontface\myfontfcFkBdA[Scale=1.1]{Junicode} % no

% map Junicode(0)/bx/sc (bold smallcaps) to Junicode(1)/m/sc (normal smallcaps of fake bold)
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{Junicode(0)}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * Junicode(1)/m/sc}{}

% for debugging fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14382/2595
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showfont}{Encoding: \f@encoding{},
  Family: \f@family{},
  Series: \f@series{},
  Shape: \f@shape{},
  Size: \f@size{}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}


% from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10524/2595
% change this to get the formatting you want
\newcommand{\parnum}{\bfseries\arabic{parcount}}

\newcounter{parcount}
\newenvironment{parnumbers}{%
   \par%
%    \reversemarginpar%
%    \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\marginpar[\hfill\parnum]{\parnum}}%
   \everypar{\stepcounter{parcount}\leavevmode\reversemarginpar{\makebox[20pt][r]{\hfill\parnum.\space}}}%
}{}




\begin{document}

\begin{parnumbers}

  {\scshape \showfont Aa} % (0)

  {\fontspec[Letters=SmallCaps]{Junicode} \showfont Aa} % (2)

  {\bfseries\scshape \showfont Aa} % (0)

  \showfont Aa % (0)

  \normalsize \showfont Aa % (0)

  \newfontface\myfontfcScA[Scale=1.1]{Junicode} \showfont Aa % (0), but creates (3)?

  \newfontfamily\myfontfam{Junicode} \showfont Aa % (0)

  \fontspec[Scale=1.0] {Junicode} \showfont Aa % (4)

  \addfontfeature{Scale=1.0} \showfont Aa % (5)

  \fontsize{9}{10} \showfont Aa % (5)

  \fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont \showfont Aa % (5)

  \addfontfeature{Scale=0.9} \showfont Aa % (6)

  \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont \showfont Aa % (6)

  \normalsize \showfont Aa % (6)

  \begin{tikzpicture} \node { \normalsize \showfont Aa }; \end{tikzpicture} % (6)

  \showfont Aa % (6)

  \myfontfam \showfont Aa % (0)

  \normalsize \showfont Aa % (0)

  \myfontfcScA \showfont Aa % (3)

  \showfont Aa % (3)

  \normalsize \showfont Aa % (3)

  \myfontfam \showfont Aa % (0)

\end{parnumbers}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand in what this differs from the "question" example; with this I get *one more* font. At the bottom of the `.log` file you find for this example `4218 words of font info for 50 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000`; the other example gives `4210 words of font info for 49 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000`.

Comment: Sorry, @egreg - I didn't even think about the log file! I realize it is written a bit messy; but basically, I though at first that `\setfont`, `\fontspec` change an existing font setting - instead they instantiate a _new_ font family. So, I was at loss at how to change, but not instantiate unnecessarily - and it turns out, one can instead use `\newfontfamily` and commands generated by it to switch to a style, which I think is now correct in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56215/2595). Many thanks for the comment - cheers!