# How to use all variants of Latin Modern Roman with fontspec?

Tags: fontspec, latin-modern

Sorry I have minimal knowledge of how font families work in TeX. After trying to read the fontspec documentation I get more and more confused. I am trying to get as many variants of Latin Modern Roman working as I can, especially the variants of unslanted roman, oblique small caps.  Foe example I do not know how to get small caps oblique to be used when itshape and scshape are both in effect.

I originally wanted `\textup` to have the Unslanted variant of the font but doing `UprightFont = Latin Modern Roman Unslanted` would change all normal font to that as well. I thought the whole point of `\textup` and `\textrm` being separate commands is allow distinction with upshape? Anyhow because of this I am defining `\textun` for the unslanted variant.

Is it also possible to have fake bold with small caps by using, say, `weight` in fontspec such that I can put `\textsc{Abc}` in section headings (i.e. such that it works with `\bfseries`)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english,draft]{article}
% Additional Options
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
%fontspec options:
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont={* Caps}, SlantedFont={* Slanted}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontface\textun{lmromanunsl10-regular.otf} 
%I cannot use \newfontface\textun{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted} for some reason...
\begin{document}
    Latin Modern Roman normal text \newline  
    \textit{Latin Modern Roman italic text} \newline  
    \textsl{Latin Modern Roman Slanted} \newline  
    \textun{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted} \newline
    \textsc{Latin Modern Roman Caps} \newline  
    \emph{\textsc{Latin Modern Roman Oblique small caps?}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a source to the fonts? I can't find any SmallCaps variant in my set.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You need the OTF version from here:
http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your original `\textun` acted as an switch (like `\itshape`) so I redefined `\textun` as

```
\newfontface\unshape[]{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted} 
\newcommand\textun[1]{{\unshape #1}}
```

### `\textrm`, `\textup` and/or `\textun`

You easily could re-defined `\textrm` and `\textup` with

```
\renewcommand\textup[1]{{\unshape #1}} % see section "Code" for \unshape
\renewcommand\textrm[1]{{\unshape #1}}
normal \textup{unslanted} normal \textup{unslanted}
```

which gives you
[image: rm and up as un]

While that does work it is not a good idea. `\textrm` and `\textup` are well implemented macros. Who knows which package you might break?

Besides, *`\textrm` and `\textup` aren't the same,* for LaTeX applies:

- `rm` (roman) is a family specifier (“[Serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_weight#Serifs)”). Families are (generally) **r**o**m**an/serif/antiqua, **s**ans-seri**f**/grotesque and **t**ypewri**t**er.
- `up` is a shape specifier (“[Slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_weight#Slope)”). Other shapes are: **it**alics, oblique/**sl**anted/**sl**oped, **S**ᴍᴀʟʟ **C**ᴀᴘꜱ
- And then there are series (“[Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_weight#Weight)”):  light, **m**e**d**ium<sup>†</sup>, semi-bold, bold, heavy, … (names and definitions may vary). `bf` stands for **b**old**f**ace.

#### Code (Example)

```
{\sffamily sans-serif family \textrm{roman family} sf \textup{up shape} sf} \par
{\itshape italics \textrm{roman family} it \textup{up shape} it}
```

#### Output (Example)

[image: rm and up]

### FakeBold and SmallCaps

Borrowing from [sdaau's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56097/16595) the OP himself has found the following map-workaround:

#### Code (FakeBold SmallCaps)

```
\fontspec[
    FakeBold=4,
    SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}
    ]{Latin Modern Roman}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{LatinModernRoman(0)}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * LatinModernRoman(1)/m/sc}{}
```

### Font sizes?

The following code shows these fonts included in the PDF:

- 5: Regular
- 7: Regular, Italic
- 8: Regular, Italic, Slant
- 9: Regular, Italic, Slant
- 10: Regular (+Caps), Italic, Oblique Caps, Slant, Unsl
- 12: Regular, Italic, Slant
- 17: Regular, Slant

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,draft]{article}
% Additional Options
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%fontspec options:
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps},
    SlantedFont={* Slanted},
    ItalicFeatures  = {
        SmallCapsFont = {LMRomanCaps10-Oblique}
    },
    ]{Latin Modern Roman}

\newfontface\unshape[]{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted} 
\newcommand\textun[1]{{\unshape #1}}

\fontspec[
    FakeBold=4,
    SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}
    ]{Latin Modern Roman}
\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{LatinModernRoman(0)}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * LatinModernRoman(1)/m/sc}{}

\def\testtext{%
    Latin Modern Roman normal text \par
    \textit{Latin Modern Roman italic text} \par
    \textsl{Latin Modern Roman Slanted} \par
    {\textun{Latin Modern Roman Unslanted}} \par
    \textsc{Latin Modern Roman Caps} \par
    \emph{\textsc{Latin Modern Roman Oblique small caps?}} \par
    {\bfseries\scshape Latin Modern Roman Caps FakeBold}\par
    \null\par
}
\begin{document}
{\tiny\testtext}
{\scriptsize\testtext}
{\footnotesize\testtext}
{\small\testtext}
\testtext
{\large\testtext}
{\Large\testtext}
{\LARGE\testtext}
{\huge\testtext}
{\Huge\testtext}
\end{document}
```

### Output (normal size)

[image: normal size output]

---

<sup>†</sup> Yes there are `\mdshape` and `\textmd`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with using file names specifically the optical sizes doesn't scale automatically (Sec 8.6 of the `fontspec` manual). Let me try without using the file names explicitly

Comment: I tried nesting `BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFeatures={AutoFakeBold=4,FakeBold=4}}` but it failed to produce any results for \bfseries\scshape :(

Comment: @MobiusPizza Something like [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56097/16595) might help you here, but I couldn't get it to work with LMR.

Comment: Thanks I was looking at it too. I have got it to work now, edited the code. Great answer by the way and thanks.

Comment: @MobiusPizza Glad I could clear some things up. And good catch with `(Auto)FakeBold`!

Comment: Great solution! But I had to replace `EU1` by `\UTFencname` to make it work.