# What does this font correspond to?

Tags: fonts

I have this piece of thesis and I would know what font is. Should be Times New Roman? I think not. I compared but they are not totally equal

[image]

what do you say?

Here it is a link where you can show better the font:

[thesis](http://biccari.altervista.org/c/fisica/appunti/Biccari_2010_PhDthesis.pdf)

[image]

This is my result after using `lmodern` with `pdftex`. As you can see is too light respet to that in the thesis

Comment: See [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919)

Comment: I have already tried to use that url. I got errors. No one can say me directly what font it is?

Comment: No URL, have you checked the document properties? It is “[LMRoman](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm)”.

Comment: Where can I find that font? How can I use?

Comment: Depending on the engine: `\usepackage{lmodern}` (pdfLaTeX) or [How to use all variants of Latin Modern Roman with fontspec?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79086) (XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX). It is pretty much the default TeX font in a 21st century kind (accents etc).

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a duplicate of the link provided by @Qrrbrbirlbel. Didn't the answer there help? The default font now is LMRoman as already mentioned.

Comment: The site http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ (noted above) suggests Moderno FB Cond Light from Font Bureau Moderno FB,
Res PublicaWEB from Linotype Res Publica, Photina MTStd from Adobe Photina MT. I have no idea whether it's right.

Comment: I tried to use lmodern but the character it too light and doesn't correspond to that of the linked thesis

Comment: I mean that it is the right character but it is too light instead in the thesis is brighter

Comment: At this link: http://biccari.altervista.org/c/informatica/latex/sapthesis_3.2.zip I found the original class used to created the thesis. I didn't notice any particular package to recreate that text. Do you confirmed?

Comment: If you look at the template `saptheis-doc.tex`, you can see that there is a call to `txfonts` (which is a Times clone)

Answer (score 3):

[Latin Modern Roman](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Roman); a standard TeX font. If the standard weight is too light, try upgrading to *demi* as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27875/4585).

Since the dissertation is new and the author is likely to still have its source, you could try asking directly. Most PhD's are flattered by people who show interest in their dissertations.

Comment: I searched in latex font catalogue but I didn't find it

Comment: Should I use this: \usepackage{lmodern} ?

Comment: I used lmodern package. I got the correct font but it is too ''light'' respect to that in the linked thesis