# How do I use the semibold font Latin Modern Roman Demi?

Tags: fonts, formatting, bold

I have my document ready to print, except the title. Regarding purely personal and aesthetic taste, I want it with `serif` with `lmodern` font, and a bit bold.

However, for my taste, using `\normalfont` is not bold enough, while `\bfseries` is too bold for me.

***Question:*** is there a way to print it semibold?

P.-S.: (This question was originally asked using the "middle-bold" keyword.)

---

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    Not bold enough 

    {\bfseries Too bold}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: What you require is known as a `semibold` version of Latin Modern. As far as I know, there is no such version.

Comment: thx for the keyword - original post edited accordingly. I then found [Level of “boldness” changeable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/level-of-boldness-changeable) ; [How to use all variants of Latin Modern Roman with fontspec?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/how-to-use-all-variants-of-latin-modern-roman-with-fontspec)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know `fontspec` sufficiently well to understand what they do to  obtain bold small caps.

Comment: Just FYI: In some professional fonts, the SemiBold version has the same metrics as the regular. That is, the character strokes are slightly thicker, and the text does not spread out. I do not know if that is a general rule among SemiBold weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no semibold version but you could scale up a smaller font size (the code I use is okay for a short portion like a title but not suitable for longer text!): \scalebox and resizebox of the graphicx package can be used too. It is up to you to decide if this looks pleasing ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\textbf{Bold}

\font\testa=ec-lmr10 at 25pt
{\testa A bit Bold}

\font\testb=ec-lmr5 at 25pt
{\testb A bit Bold}

Not Bold
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. thank you !

Comment: @ebo There's a demi-bold, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is no semi-bold font, but there **is** a demi-bold one. The relevant type1 versions of the fonts are included in the `lmodern` package. Unfortunately, `lmodern.sty` provides no straightforward way of accessing these fonts and `lmodern` does not provide the needed `.fd` files. Fortunately, `cfr-lm` does.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[rm={proportional,lining},sf={proportional,lining},tt={tabular,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
\Huge
Not bold enough 

{\bfseries Too bold}

{\sbweight Just right}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the demi-bold lacks optical sizes, which are supported by the bold-extended. This means that at some sizes, the demi-bold looks at least as bold as the bold, if not more so:

[image: demi-bold]

Moreover, the demi-bold is not extended, as the bold is, and there is no true italic - only an oblique shape.

That said, depending on the range of sizes and shapes required, the demi-bold may still be a good option. At normal size (10pt), for example, it is at least somewhat less bold than the bold (though the PNG shows this rather less clearly than the PDF, unfortunately):

[image: demi-bold, 10pt]

The effect is still quite subtle. It may be easier to compare the same letter repeated:

[image: 2 'I's]

[Bold-extended on the left; demi-bold on the right; 10pt.]

Depending on your needs, therefore, the purpose-designed demi-bold may or may not be a better option than trying the faking strategies suggested in the other answers. At the least, it is worth noting that there certainly **is** such a font.

Answer (score 3):

This approach only works in pdflatex, where I use a pdf special to semi-embolden the font, here embodied as `\textsb[<emboldening level>]{<text>}`.

In the MWE, I show emboldment levels ranging from `.2` to `1` (default `.4`).  One can then compare to the baseline font, as well as the `\textbf` version.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
%%%%%
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w 0 0 0 rg 0 G}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\textsb[2][.4]{%
  \def\thickness{#1}%
  \outline{#2}%
}
%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \Huge Not bold enough 

    \textsb[.2]{.2 bold enough?}

    \textsb{.4 bold enough?}

    \textsb[.6]{.6 bold enough?}

    \textsb[.8]{.8 bold enough?}

    \textsb[1]{1.0 bold enough?}

    {\bfseries Too bold}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @cfr works well in PDFLaTeX, but if you’re using a modern toolchain, you will want to use `fontspec`.  Here’s one way to do that.  It sets up LaTeX-like `\textsb{}` and `\sbseries` commands that work with any fonts containing a `sb` weight.  (You could if you prefer give `\sbseries` the name `\sbweight` like in `nfss-cfr`.)

```
\documentclass[10pt, varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Scale = 1.0,
  Ligatures = {Common, Discretionary, TeX},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font = {lmromandemi10-regular}, Extension = .otf },
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font = {lmromandemi10-oblique}, Extension = .otf }
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

% The commands to select semibold weight:
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    Not bold enough

    {\bfseries Too} \textbf{bold}

    {\sbseries Just} \textsb{right}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Font Sample]

Comment: I seem to be able to use your `\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}` and 
`\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}` to set up some version of semibold even using the `lmodern` package and pdflatex. For me that already does the job. Thanks!

Comment: (I think what happens is that in my case it substitutes `\fontseries{sb}` with `\fontseries{b}`, which at least looks a little less bold than the usual extended `\fontseries{bx}`)