# Looking for semibold version of erewhon

Tags: bold

I am looking for defining a semibold Erewhon font for text mode. If there is none I'd be willing to fake it in the same manner as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290036/194729 but I don't how I can adapt that snippet.

Comment: The technique used in the answer you reference depends on the fact that there (for latin modern) the design of each character is different for different sizes, so a smaller size can be scaled up and thus at the same time become (somewhat) bolder.  I don't know whether erewhon has been created with different design sizes, and that must be true for the scaling technique to be effective.

Comment: I'm sure there is some kind of fake option in `fontspec` but I do not know it (`AutoFakeBold`? `FakeBold`?) I can show how it can look [in ConTeXt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdNck.png), where this can be done with `\definefontfeature[poormansbold][boldened-10]` and then by using that fontfeature.

Comment: A better choice is to use the font software to increase different vertical and horizontal weights.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{erewhon}
\begin{document}


One two three four five six.

{\fontspec[FakeBold=1,LetterSpace=.5]{erewhon} One two three four five six.}

{\fontspec[FakeBold=2,LetterSpace=1]{erewhon} One two three four five six.}

{\fontspec[FakeBold=3,LetterSpace=1.7]{erewhon} One two three four five six.}

{\bfseries One two three four five six.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

No real chance to get it with `pdflatex`, but you can use `FakeBold` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

You also want to define an interface for semibold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={sb}{n}{Font=*-Regular,FakeBold=3},
  FontFace={sb}{it}{Font=*-Italic,FakeBold=3},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

Medium, \textsb{Semibold}, \textbf{Bold}

{\itshape Medium, \textsb{Semibold}, \textbf{Bold}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to replace boldface with the (faked) semibold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Regular,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=3},
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=3},
]

\begin{document}

Medium \textbf{Bold}

{\itshape Medium, \textbf{Bold}}

\end{document}
```

[image]