# "Rare" ligatures in LuaLaTeX and LMR font

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures

How do I get "Rare/Discretionary" ligatures with the Latin Modern Roman Font in LuaLateX?

So far I have loaded the `fontspec` package and have tried several different approaches the most promising looking being: ([from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79086/how-to-use-all-variants-of-latin-modern-roman-with-fontspec))

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare,SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Unfortunately though, the Q of Queen still has a short tail, film however has the correct ligature.
\end{document}
```

I fear the answer may be: Use XeTeX. However I am using LuaLateX for drawing trees and therefore could not move to XeTeX without significant work. (As far as I am aware.)

Comment: The Latin Modern fonts don't provide that feature.

Comment: @egreg That explains the problem! For future reference where can I check this sort of thing for myself?

Comment: There's no general method, I'm afraid. The Latin Modern fonts do have the `dlig` feature, but I don't really know which ones it enables.

Comment: @egreg Do you, by any chance, have any recommendations for similar fonts which do support this?

Comment: Looking with FontForge, I see that the `dlig` table just implements the standard TeX ligatures. As far as I know Libertinus Serif has the long tailed Q (enabled by default).

Comment: @egreg FontForge looks to be a very interesting bit of software. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `otfinfo -f <font file>` will tell you which features a font file supports. However, it won't, on its own, tell you what exactly each feature does for that font, as @egreg points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ligatures are font dependent; it's the font designer/developer who decides which one to enable in the various tables.

For instance, Latin Modern Roman has a `dlig` feature, which is enabled in `fontspec` with `Ligatures=Rare` or `Ligatures=Discretionary`, but the relative subtable just shows that essentially the standard TeX ligatures are enabled (which is already done by the default `Ligatures=TeX` option.

In general it should be a duty of the font distributor to provide instructions about what features the font is endowed with. Unfortunately this is not done very frequently. Using FontForge is most of the times the simplest way to get the relevant information.

The picture shows a screen shot of how I looked at the subtable responsible for the `dlig` feature.

[image]